# TestNG @Test methods do not executes in specified order in xml, when we add dependencies in class

Tags: testng, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

If I have class and xml as follows :

```
class Test 
{

  @Test 
  public void method1() {}

  @Test (dependsOn = "method1") 
  public void method2() {}

  @Test (dependsOn = "method2") 
  public void method3() {}



  @Test (dependsOn = "method1") 
  public void otherMethod() {}

}
```

XML

```
<test name="XYZ" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
     <class name="Test">
      <methods>
        <include name="method1"/> 
        <include name="method2"/> 
        <include name="method3"/> 
        <include name="otherMethod"/> 
       </methods>
      </class>
     </classes>
    </test>
```

NOTE : Assume all methods would pass

**Order of execution:**

`method1` >
`method2` >
`otherMethod` >
`method3`

Because `method2` and `otherMethod` are depends on `method1`, they execute first and then `method3` executes, although `method3` is present before `otherMethod` in XML.

How can we execute such methods, in the sequence, we defined in XML?

**Expected Order:**

`method1` > `method2` > `method3` > `otherMethod`

Answer (score 0):

It seems otherMethod depends on method3 as strict order is required. In this case, I would recommend adding this dependency into otherMethod

```
@Test (dependsOnMethods  = {"method1", "method3"}) 
public void otherMethod() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. dependsOnMethods  = {"method1", "method3"} : by doing this, for execution of otherMethod() - method1 and method3, have to be passed. But In my case otherMethod is not logically depends on method3, i.e. even though method3 fails - otherMethod should execute.